# Error report while activating conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have installed python 3.7 latest anaconda. After successful installation, I opened the navigator and inside there was base(root) environment, I tried opening the terminal from there. When I open the terminal, it sends me error report and from the terminal screen I cannot see that I am currently in base environment.

I tried activating conda environment explicitly using following command and got error report again:

```
conda activate base
```

**Error Report:**

```
C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi>conda activate base

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 138, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 996, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 180, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 154, in activate
        builder_result = self.build_activate(self.env_name_or_prefix)
      File "C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 288, in build_activate
        return self._build_activate_stack(env_name_or_prefix, False)
      File "C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 314, in _build_activate_stack
        conda_prompt_modifier = self._prompt_modifier(prefix, conda_default_env)
      File "C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 639, in _prompt_modifier
        name=basename(prefix),
    KeyError: 'fast_rcnn_env'

`$ C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py shell.cmd.exe activate base`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\condabin\..\S
                          cripts\conda.exe
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\Fariha.Abbasi
          NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
                     PATH=C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;C:\Users\Fari
                          ha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\U
                          sers\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C
                          :\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:
                          \Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\User
                          s\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\Fariha.
                          Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppDat
                          a\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Fariha.Abba
                          si\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Fariha.A
                          bbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Fariha.Ab
                          basi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\DockerDe
                          sktop\version-bin;C:\Program
                          Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program
                          Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.3.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpen
                          JDK\jdk-12.0.1.12-hotspot\bin;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Pro
                          grams\Python\Python36;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2
                          \wbin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDO
                          WS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Program
                          Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\C
                          hrome\Application;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin;C:\User
                          s\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts;C:\User
                          s\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-
                          packages\tensorflow;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\L
                          ocal\Programs\Python\Python36;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Mic
                          rosoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Programs\Micro
                          soft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Python2
                          7;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\Downloads;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Loca
                          l\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Powe
                          rAppsCLI\Microsoft.PowerApps.CLI.0.1.51\tools;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\A
                          ppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts;C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\A
                          ppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
       user config file : C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.10
    conda-build version : 3.18.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.1
       base environment : C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.10 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

Upload successful.

C:\Users\Fariha.Abbasi>
```

[Here is screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiTCS.png)
where it can be clearly seen that it has not activated the environment.

Comment: I'm confused by your output: You report trying to use `conda activate base`, but the error shows that you were trying to activate `fast_rcnn_env`. Which is it?

Comment: No, I am not aware of fast_rcnn_env. Neither I am trying to use it. I checked my list of envs as well and there is no environment present other than base. I am confused with "fast_rcnn_env" too

Comment: Okay, that's strange. From the error report it looks like you are in **base** (`activate environment: base`), but it might set that as soon as you start running a `conda cmd`. If you start a new terminal session and run `conda info`, what does it say?